# Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib : valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am re-signing a third party vendors app for enterprise distribution. I go through my usual re-signing process and it will install OK on an iOS10 device. However when I run the app it immediately crashes and I see the following in the debug log:

> iPad amfid[224] :
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB77EC6D-32E0-4762-B11B-9894799DD96C/ScannerPro.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
>   not valid: 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this
>   executable was not found

Comment: It would help to know what your re-signing method is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing step was

> codesign -f -s “iPhone Distribution:[company name]" '--entitlements'
>   'entitlements.plist' AppName.app/Frameworks/*

After doing this, and then resigning the overall app, the IPA launched successfully on both iOS9 and 10